# unexpected error by using passing by reference

Tags: c

i want to use passing by reference but the compiler said that error:expected ';'.

after i spend many time to find the error,,i'm still don't understand why the code not working.

then after i fix the missing semicolon,,i've another error said expected ')'

```
int around(int &count1,int &count2,int &count3);

int volume(int &v1,int &v2,int &v3);

int large(int &a1,int &a2,int &a3);



int main() {
  int l,w,h,sum;

  printf("Input Length : ");
  scanf("%d",&l );

  printf("Input Width : ");
  scanf("%d",&w );

  printf("Input Height : ");
  scanf("%d",&h );
  printf("\n\n");

  sum = around(l,w,h);

  printf("Around = %d\n",sum );

  sum = volume(l,w,h);
  printf("Volume = %d\n",sum );

  sum = large(l,w,h);
  printf("Large = %d\n",sum );
  return 0;
}


int around(int &count1,int &count2, int &count3){
  int value;
  value = 4*(count1+count2+count3);

  return (value);
}

int volume(int &v1,int &v2,int &v3){
  int val;
  val = v1*v2*v3;

  return (val);
}

int large(int &a1,int &a2,int &a3){
  int sm;
  sm = 2*((a1*a2) + (a1*a3) + (a2*a3));
  return (sm);
}
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++? References are a C++ feature. It would help to have the exact error message, which should include a line number, and an indication of which line that is in your file. You code compiles as C++ for me.

Comment: i'm not sure it's C or C++ feature.

Comment: this is C++ code. If you're trying to use a C compiler, it's going to complain at you. There is no pass by reference in C.

Comment: The examples you gave do not even require pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References, i.e. an argument preceeded by an `&` like in your `int around(int &count1,int &count2,int &count3)` is a C++-feature and not available in C.

Anyway, none of your functions is actually altering the arguments, so passing "by reference" makes no sense.

Changing all your functions (and their forward declarations) that look like

```
int around(int &count1,int &count2,int &count3) ...
```

into

```
int around(int count1, int  count2, int  count3) ...
```

Should solve the issue for a C-compiler.

For a C++-compiler it would have worked anyway.